# Convert Java/Json to formatted HTML

Tags: java, html, json, spring-boot

I have and list of employees with the below structure

```
{
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "name": "sonoo",
        "salary": 56000,
        "married": true
      },
      {
        "name": "xoxoxox",
        "salary": 55000,
        "married": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I transform this data to a well-formatted HTML which has CSS and would look something like this

[image]

Q1: How do I map the employee's data to the UI in spring boot?

Q2. Is there an API to stream JSON response to HTML in java?

PS: I have to create a generic HTML template that would take dynamic values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected result?

Comment: Could you be more specific. Is this a complete page submit request or Ajax request?

Comment: @Vipul Its a complete page request

Comment: @iota I'm pretty new to this, just looking up articles. I know It should be easy to parse JSON within HTML. I'm not sure if there is an API that can help me call with forwarding json in HTML from helper method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, so I can only answer on assumptions. Assuming you're using a third-party service to get the JSON data in your java application and then sending that JSON data to the front end. You can directly send the JSON as is to the front end using Jackson Library. Or if you are using a templating engine such as thymeleaf. Then You can simply convert the JSON response to the Object at your java end again you can use Jackson here. And send that object to the thymeleaf. If you are sending a List then you can use th:each attribute in thymeleaf to iterate over your list and print it in your desired way.

```html
<ul>
    <li th:each="emp: ${employees}">
      <p th:value="${emp.name}"/>
      <p th:value="${emp.email}"/>
      <p th:value="${emp.phone}"/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Converting JSON to JavaObject : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-a-json-to-java-object-using-the-jackson-library-in-java

p.s. Also if you are using Java Object then you don't have to convert that to JSON to send it to the client Jackson will do that internally for you. and for thymeleaf, you can use modal to send object.

Also, Jackson is the default JSON parser in web dependencies of spring boot. so if you are using spring boot web starter then you don't have to insert Jackson into pom.xml it will be available to you.